# skype cdn error caused during implementation

Tags: javascript, skype, skypedeveloper

Hi I am trying to integrate skype chat action in my application.

Click on **CUSTOMER support**

Few days ago I used below url.  as cdn
https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js

[**old fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/75n9zvLo/)

But now that cdn not working.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MS_APP_CLIENT_ID' of undefined

So I used new cdn.
from suggestion and after some research I found new cdn to use
https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.js

[**new fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/m5uefxL3/)

This new cdn also not working.
In console I can see lots of error for this cdn.
Please suggest .

```js
Skype.ui({
            "name": "chat",
            "element": "SkypeButton_Call_lemonkazi_1",
            "participants": ["lemonkazi"]
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<script src="https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_lemonkazi_1" class="homeBtn homeBtnContact" onclick="SkypeWebControl.SDK.Chat.startChat({ConversationType: 'person', ConversationId: 'lemonkazi'});">
            <span>Customer Support</span>
        <iframe style="display:none;" id="_detectSkypeClient_1552468984987"></iframe><p id="SkypeButton_Call_lemonkazi_1_paraElement" style="font-size:14px; color:#444444"><a href="javascript://" onclick="SkypeWebControl.SDK.Chat.startChat({ConversationType: 'person', ConversationId: 'lemonkazi'});"><div class="skype-button" style="pointer-events: none;"><div></div></div><img src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/images/skype-buttons/chatbutton_16px.png" alt="Skype chat, instant message" role="Button" style="border:0; margin:16px; vertical-align:-20px;"></a></p></div>
```

From my server I got below error message

> "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: SkypeWebControl is not defined",

[image]

Comment: What is not working? GET for the js file fails? or Clicking on the chat button doesn't work? The errors in the console should be helpful. Can you post them?

Comment: @acid_srvnn this is same as this error. "GET https://swc.cdn.skype.com/vendors/uicomponent-bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404".

Comment: Seems the difference is due to some env variable used inside that skyway sdk js file. When is env is df , the further requests use `latest-swc.cdn` and if the env is prod, the further requests use `swc.cdn`. In your failure scenario, env is prod, so the GET url is formed as `https://swc.cdn.skype.com/vendors/uicomponent-bundle.js` and the url does return 404. Whereas `https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/vendors/uicomponent-bundle.js` does return the proper js file.  Maybe you can use this info and analyze further.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the Skype Web Control for which a fix has been deployed over the weekend. Are you still seeing the issue?

Comment: still in console I am getting this error. https://imgur.com/a/Gv8itVb I used this two link    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>